# Recentering if multiple-cursors goes out the screen?

Tags: multiple-cursors

How can I make the functions of `multiple-cursors` recenter if the next or previous candidate if not show in current screen automatically? Although I known I can do it by <kbd>C-v</kbd> and <kbd>M-v</kbd> manually. Thanks in advance !